# Capturing radio input value in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

How can I get the value of a radio input and pass it to a function using @click in Vue.js. 
I actually want to do something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="phone" :value="mobile.value" @click = "setPrice(value)">
```

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what your asking [click here to see the answer](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/v3fez9h5/)

Checkout this straightforward example how input radio works with vue.js

```
<input type="radio" id="one" value="One" v-model="picked">
<label for="one">One</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="two" value="Two" v-model="picked">
<label for="two">Two</label>
<br>
```

*and the script:*

```
export default {
  data: {
    return {
      picked: 'One'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This just captures the value of the radio input. What I actually need is to get that value, pass it to a function in a store.js and that functions updates some other value in the store.state.

Comment: Hmm ok.I answered how you can do this and made an example to jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same question and it was referencing the event object that I was missing. Now it works.

Answer (score 3):

Just provide the function name:

```
@click="setPrice"
```

You should then have access to the value:

```
function setPrice(event) {
  const value = event.target.value;
}
```